# Regular expression-based list matching in R

Tags: regex, r, list, subset

I have two lists (more exactly, character atomic vectors) that I want to compare using regular expressions to produce a sub-set of one of the lists. I can use a 'for' loop for this, but is there some simpler code? Following exemplifies my case:

```
# list of unique cities
city <- c('Berlin', 'Perth', 'Oslo')

# list of city-months, like 'New York-Dec'
temp <- c('Berlin-Jan', 'Delhi-Jan', 'Lima-Feb', 'Perth-Feb', 'Oslo-Jan')

# need sub-set of 'temp' for only 'Jan' month for only the items in 'city' list:
#   'Berlin-Jan', 'Oslo-Jan'
```

Added clarification: In the actual case that I am seeking code for, the values of the 'month' equivalent are more complex, and rather random alphanumeric values with only the first two characters having informational value of my interest (has to be '01').

Added actual case example:

```
# equivalent of 'city' in the first example
# values match pattern TCGA-[0-9A-Z]{2}-[0-9A-Z]{4}
patient <- c('TCGA-43-4897', 'TCGA-65-4897', 'TCGA-78-8904', 'TCGA-90-8984')

# equivalent of 'temp' in the first example
# values match pattern TCGA-[0-9A-Z]{2}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[\d]{2}[0-9A-Z]+
sample <- c('TCGA-21-5732-01A333', 'TCGA-43-4897-01A159', 'TCGA-65-4897-01T76', 'TCGA-78-8904-11A70')

# sub-set wanted (must have '01' after the 'patient' ID part)
#   'TCGA-43-4897-01A159', 'TCGA-65-4897-01T76'
```

Comment: show us your "actual" case please.

Comment: I have added an actual case example. I now realize it is important.

Comment: You don't want: `'TCGA-78-8904-11A70'`??

Comment: It has to have a '01' and not '11'; i.e., 'TCGA-78-8904-01A70' but not 'TCGA-78-8904-11A70' fits the criteria.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
temp <- temp[grepl("Jan", temp)]
temp[sapply(strsplit(temp, "-"), "[[", 1) %in% city]
# [1] "Berlin-Jan" "Oslo-Jan"
```

Even better, borrowing the idea from @agstudy:

```
> temp[temp %in% paste0(city, "-Jan")]
# [1] "Berlin-Jan" "Oslo-Jan"
```

**Edit:** How about this?

```
> sample[gsub("(.*-01).*$", "\\1", sample) %in% paste0(patient, "-01")]
# [1] "TCGA-43-4897-01A159" "TCGA-65-4897-01T76"
```

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, but the item values in my actual case are more complex. I have now clarified this in my question.

Comment: Arun, thanks for the edited code. For the actual case example, it will fail if a patient item value had '-01'. But this slight modification of your snippet seems to work well: sample[gsub("(TCGA-[0-9A-Z]{2}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-01).*$", "\\1", sample) %in% paste0(patient, "-01")]

Comment: @user594694, I use the greedy search `.*-01`, it'll search until the last `-01`. So, I don't think it'll be a problem unless you've a patient: `TCGA-78-8904-017190-01` or something like that.. That is, it won't be a problem if your patient is: `TCGA-01-0189-017190`. Try it out.

Comment: You are right. Thanks again. Your code worked well with my full case (~400 patient items and ~1200 sample items).

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution after the others, with your new requirements:

```
sample[na.omit(pmatch(paste0(patient, '-01'), sample))]
```

Comment: @user594694, blindJesse Note: This won't work if the exact partial match pattern occurs in sample more than once, for example: `sample <- c("TCGA-21-5732-01A333", "TCGA-21-5732-01B859")`. `pmatch(paste0(patient, "-01"), sample)` in this case returns `NA, NA`.

Comment: Good point...I guess it depends somewhat on the expected dataset, but I suppose in general this solution won't work

Answer (score 2):

You can use `gsub`

```
x <- gsub(paste(paste(city,collapse='-Jan|'),'-Jan',sep=''),1,temp)
> temp[x==1]
[1] "Berlin-Jan" "Oslo-Jan"
```

the pattern here is :

```
 "Berlin-Jan|Perth-Jan|Oslo-Jan"
```

Comment: brilliant use of `paste`. but it could be then even more shorter (I've adapted the solution by borrowing your idea). (all out of votes, I'll promptly upvote again when allowed :))

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with two partial string matches...

```
temp[agrep("Jan",temp)[which(agrep("Jan",temp) %in% sapply(city, agrep, x=temp))]]
# [1] "Berlin-Jan" "Oslo-Jan"
```

As a function just for fun...

```
fun <- function(x,y,pattern) y[agrep(pattern,y)[which(agrep(pattern,y) %in% sapply(x, agrep, x=y))]]
# x is a vector containing your data for filter
# y is a vector containing the data to filter on
# pattern is the quoted pattern you're filtering on

fun(temp, city, "Jan")
# [1] "Berlin-Jan" "Oslo-Jan"
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice function. It works for the example I provided but fails with the actual case. I have now provided a sample of the actual case in my question. Note: By mistake you have the argument order switched in fun().